# arrayWithObjects... is there a shortcut for using the same object?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

arrayWithObjects... is there a shortcut for using the same object "a" or any object?

```
NSMutableArray *kkk = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"a", @"a", @"a", nil];
```

something like:

```
NSMutableArray *kkk = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: [repeat: @"a", 4] , nil];
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a category method out of this, something like:

```
@interface NSMutableArray (Additions)
 - (void)addObject:(id)object numberOfTimes:(NSUInteger)times;
@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (Additions)
- (void)addObject:(id)object numberOfTimes:(NSUInteger)times
{
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        [self addObject:object];
    }
}
@end
```

(Depending on your circumstances, you may want to create a copy of the object instead of adding the same object multiple times to the same array)

Then you could just do this:

```
[array addObject:@"a" numberOfTimes:4];
```

Comment: @Kristen Martinson: The documentation exposes everything public. If you don't see it there, it's not there.

Comment: There isn't a method to do this because it isn't something that's done often. Its trivial to implement it yourself via a category though.